# Как вывести содержимое list? c#

Tags: c#, list, display

Выводит вот это:
ConsoleApp2.Product
ConsoleApp2.Product
ConsoleApp2.Product
Надо чтобы он вывел содержимое этого списка

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>() { new Product("Апельсин", "999"), new Product("Fll", "Beat"), new Product("Раб", "Ч") };

bool isOn = true;

while (isOn)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Какое действие хотите выполнить?");
    Console.WriteLine("1 - Увидеть инвентарь у продавца, 2 - Купить, 3 - Запросить название и описание продукта, 4 - Выйти из магазина");
    int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((products[i]));
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
            {

            }
            break;

        case 4:
            isOn = false;
            break;
    }
}


class Product
{
    public string ProductName, Description;

    public Product(string productName, string description)
    {
        ProductName = productName;
        Description = description;
    }

    //функция не работает, сам не понимаю почему
    public void ShowProductList(List<Product> List)
    {
        foreach (var product in List)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В классе `Product` надо переопределить метод `ToString()`.

Comment: Вас же интересует как вывести данные из объектов класса `Product`, верно? Тогда почему вы решили его не показывать в вопросе?

Comment: @aepot, добавил

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо переопределить метод `ToString()`. Он вызывается, когда вы пытаетесь передать объект класса `Product` в метод `Console.WriteLine()`.

Т.к он у вас изначально не был переопределен (ключевое слово `override` в сигнатуре метода), то выводилось полное имя класса (т.е `ПространствоИмен.НазваниеКласса`, в вашем случае `ConsoleApp2.Product`). Метод `ToString()` наследуется от класса `object` (от него в принципе все классы, структуры наследуются, просто неявно.)

Про переопределения метода `ToString()` можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

```
class Product
{
   public string Name;
   public int Description;
   //Ваши методы и конструкторы
   //...
   
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return $"{Name} - {Description}";
   }
}
```

Так же, вы можете выводить непосредственно поля вашего класса, обращаясь к объекту:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>(); //допустим он заполнен элементами

foreach(Product item in products)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} - {item.Description}");
}
```

Comment: Метод `ToString` предназначен в первую очередь для вывода отладочной информации, для разработчика, а не для пользователя. Иногда она совпадает, но не всегда. Правильней создать специальный метод, как в ответе Blackmeser. Ну или использовать второй ваш вариант.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я с вами абсолютно согласен, но, так как в контексте вопроса был момент с тем, что выводится "ConsoleApp3.Product" вместо нормального вывода, поэтому я и написал про ToString

Answer (score 2):

```
class Product
{
    //добавить:
    public string ShowNameAndDescr => $"{ProductName}\t{Description}"
    //функция ShowProductList поменять Console.WriteLine(product); на 
    public void ShowProductList(List<Product> List)
    {
        //код до не менять
        Console.WriteLine(product?.ShowNameAndDescr);
        //код после не менять
    }
}
```